# Taking the continuum limit of $U(N)$ gauge theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, gauge-theory, ads-cft, partition-function

I would like to draw your attention to appendix $C$ on page 38 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.3740).

- The equation $C.2$ there seems to be evaluating the sum $\sum_R \chi _R (U^m)$ in equation 3.16 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0310285). I understand that $U \in U(N_c)$ group and then with $N_f$ (fundamental?) hypermultiplets it seems that apparently the following is being claimed to be true,

$\sum _R \chi _R (U^m) = 2N_f [Tr U^m + Tr U^{-m}]$

Can someone help derive the above?

- The first line of equation $C.4$ seems to be the same as equation $5.3$ of [this earlier linked paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0310285) but not quite...
- I was pretty much confused with the idea in equation $C.5$ and $C.6$ of thinking the eigenvalues of the $U(N_c)$ group on the circle to be given by a distribution function $\rho (\theta) \geq 0$ with a mysterious normalization as in equation $C.5$.

  I would be glad if someone can help understand how equation C.6 was determined.
  A lot of steps seem to be skipped here which I found hard to reinstate!
- Going by [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.1435) it seems that the original more general equation $2.43$ on page 17 has two possible limits as in equation $2.45$ on page 17 when there are $c$ matter fields in the adjoint and $N_c \rightarrow \infty$ or equation $2.48$ in the Veneziano limit with fundamental matter fields.

  I would like to know the derivation/reference for the equations 2.45 and 2.48 cited above.

  I guess this is one of the most educative means of taking the Veneziano limit in which AdS/CFT is supposed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character $\chi_R : G \to \mathbb{C}$ of a representation $R$ is defined by $\chi_R(U) = Tr_R(U)$, namely by taking the trace of $U$ in the representation $R$. See for example Appendix A of [Aharony et al.](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0310285). Then the equation you write seems reasonable: presumably there are $N_f$ hypermultiplets, each with  fundamental  and anti-fundamental fields that give $Tr(U^m)$ and $Tr(U^{-m})$
respectively in the sum over $R$. The trace is taken of the matrix $U$ because the fields are in the fundamental.

The factor of 2 should come from the details of which representations exactly are being summed over, the field content of the hypermultiplets, etc., which I didn't try to follow.

Now, regarding the distribution of eigenvalues that appears in (C.5), let me give you a physical explanation of where this comes from. They consider the thermodynamics of a theory on a sphere, so the topology is that of a sphere times $S^1$ -- the Euclidean compact time. In this case there is a zero-mode of the gauge field, which comes from the fact that you can turn on a constant field in the thermal direction. This mode cannot be removed by a gauge transformation (in general), so in a path integral you need to integrate over it. This is explained for example in section 4.1 of [Aharony et al](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0310285). You can use a gauge transformation to diagonalize this zero-mode matrix, so you are left with the discrete eigenvalues of the matrix to integrate over. You can also show that these eigenvalues live on a circle, because you can shift them by $2\pi$ (in some normalization) using a gauge transformation, so you need to integrate them over a circle. In the large $N$ limit you have an infinite number of such eigenvalues, but they are still restricted to live on a circle. So you need to describe them using a density, and that is what they call the distribution $\rho$.

Edit: adding explanation of (C.6)

To derive (C.6), consider first the sum

$$ \sum_i \cos(n \alpha_i) = N \int_0^{2\pi} \rho(\theta) \cos(n\theta) $$

where $\rho(\theta) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i \delta(\theta - \alpha_i)$. Notice that $\rho$ has the correct normalization.

When taking $N \to \infty$ the delta functions in $\rho$ will become very dense, and we will be able to approximate $\rho$ by a smooth function, whose value at $\theta$ depends on the density of the delta functions across the small interval $[\theta,\theta+\epsilon]$. This will be a good approximation because the function $\cos(n\theta)$ that we are integrating over will not vary much in these intervals, so averaging it instead of sampling it will not change the result by much. When we reach the limit $N=\infty$ this will no longer be an approximation, because the delta functions will become continuous.

So this explains the derivation of the second term in (C.6). As for the first term, the idea is similar except that you have two integrals over $\theta,\theta'$ corresponding to the $i,j$ sums. The contributions from the $i=j$ terms ($\theta=\theta'$ in the integral) are subleading in the large $N$ limit: they scale as $N$ while the rest of it scales as $N^2$, so they are neglected.

Now, replace $\cos(n(\theta-\theta')) = \cos(n\theta) \cos(n\theta') + \sin(n\theta) \sin(n \theta')$. Notice that in the path integral over $\rho$ you may consider only eigenvalue distributions that are symmetric under $\theta \to -\theta$, because the original integrand is invariant under this. This is explicitly mentioned for example in [Schnitzer](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0402219), who does the same computation. So this means that $\int d\theta \rho \sin(n\theta) = 0$. I think it should be clear from this point.

Comment: @ Guy Gur-Ari Each of the $N_f$ hypermultiplets I think has 2 $N=2$ chiral multiplets one in the adjoint and the other in the conjuagte adjoint (= adjoint) of the gauge group. Now we have $\chi_{adj} = \chi_{\bar{adj}} = \chi_{fund}\times \chi_{anti-fund}$. So each hypermultiplet should have contributed a $2\chi_{fund}\times \chi_{anti-fund}$..right?

Comment: I can see this general argument of needing to describe the eigenvalue of a $U(N)$ matrix by a density on the circle buts its the specific re-writing of that as in equation C.6 that is puzzling me. It would be a great help if you can may be write in a few lines about how that equation was gotten!

Comment: They matter multiplets they consider in appendix C are in the fundamental, as they write in the beginning of section 3.2 (a bit before they refer to the appendix). I added the explanation of (C.6) to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updates! I think I am missing something here. In the beginning of section 2.2 (page 7) don't they say that the 2 N=2 chiral multiplets inside the N=3 hypermultiplet are in conjugate representations of the gauge group? Then is it wrong to think that these 2 N=2 chiral components are in $Adj = \bar{Adj}$ of the gauge group? If the $N_f$ hypermultiplets are in the fundamental then what is the representation in which the 2 $N=2$ chiral multiplets fall into? It will be great if you can clarify this point!

Comment: As they say, in the $N=3$ theory you can have hypermultiplets, and each hypermultiplet has two chiral multiplets: one in a rep $R$ and one in $\bar{R}$. It is not necessary that $R$ is the adjoint. A bit below the place you mention they consider various possibilities for $R$, only one of which is the adjoint. If you say that a hypermultiplet is 'fundamental' (which I think is not a precise statement although its meaning is clear), it means that you have one chiral multiplet in the fundamental and one in the anti-fundamental.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Can you give me a reference where these massless multiplets of $N=2$ and $N=3$ supersymmetry in $2+1$ dimensions are derived from scratch? Like if you can help with this previous question of mine,http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33023/21-cal-n-2-and-cal-n-3-massless-supersymmetry-multiplet  That would be a huge help!

Comment: I don't have a reference but the story is similar to the multiplets in $d=4$, which are derived in any textbook on SUSY. You can repeat this exercise in $d=3$.

Comment: I am not so sure. In d=4 the special thing that happens is that the anti-commutation between the Qs is diagonal and hence half of then go to 0 and the other half works like the Clifford algebra. In d=3 this simplification doesn't exist because of the peculiarities of the Gamma matrices at that dimension. Hence I would like to know if there is a standard reference which explains the multiplet construction in d=3.

Comment: I said it is similar, not the same. It seems to me this discussion has strayed from the original question. Why not post it as a new question?

Comment: I had already asked the separate question as linked from my previous comment. It has remained unanswered. BTW, I have awarded you the bounty. Thanks for the help! Hope to see you at that other question of mine too!

Comment: I have put up a slightly more edited version of that question, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33023/21-cal-n-2-and-cal-n-3-massless-supersymmetry-multiplet It would be great to have your help.

Comment: I think my previous question was not worded properly and I made hopefully a better statement here, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34192/some-questions-about-flavour-and-r-symmetry-in-21-cal-n-3-theory Would be glad to see you there!

Comment: @GuyGur-Ari Some recent thoughts brought me back to this discussion with you. By your construction $\rho_n$ is real - and hence when they go from 5.6 to 5.10 in the paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0310285v6.pdf they should have gotten a square-root - but they don't - it seems that their \rho_n is complex - can you kindly explain this point?